# I am getting an error while installing pytessereact on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
!apt-get install pytesseract
```

On writing above command in google colab, I got this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package pytesseract
```

Comment: Read here : [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip` --

```
!pip install pytesseract
```

See: https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#installation

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try this out

```
pip install -v    
!pip install pyenchant
!pip install pyenchant
```